# Why do I have to press enter twice to execute the Foreach-Object Cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

<sup>Editor's note:

* This question boils down to: When entering a *multi-line* command on the PowerShell *command line*, why do I have to press Enter *twice* to submit it? [Tony Hinkle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754512/45375) explains why.

* The part about the same command also needing an Enter keystroke when run from a *script* was based on a misinterpretation - the command didn't need a keystroke, it was simply *still running*.</sup>

I'm piping objects to a Foreach-Object Cmdlet and I noticed that when I run it from a script, it just sits there, and that when I run it by typing the code in I end up having to press enter twice after the last curly brace to get it to work again.

```
gci $path -recurse | %{ 
    ...
}
echo "test"
```

Is there a way to avoid this?  So that the code just keeps running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type a script into the PowerShell command window line by line, it needs a way to know that you are done entering the script, so entering a blank line is the cue for it to run the script.  To avoid this, type everything on the same line:

```
gci $path -recurse | %{ $_ } ; echo "test"
```

Comment: Okay and I just noticed that my script was actually still running, and I thought they were one in the same problem.  Thanks!

Comment: There was more in that folder than I thought there was.